# The definition of a sequence converging.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to t he number L if for every positive number $\epsilon$ there corresponds an integer $N$ such that for all $n$,
$$n > N \implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$$
If no such number $L$ exists, we say that $\{a_n\}$ diverges. If $\{a_n\}$ converges to L, we write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$$

I am having trouble understanding this definition in my textbook. Specifically when they use $\epsilon$, $N$, and $n$. Is $\epsilon$ the values in the sequence, $n$ the n-th term of the sequence, and $N$ an arbitrary integer? Could someone explain this to me?

*edit

Show that $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$.

The implication will hold if $\dfrac{1}{n}< \epsilon$ or $n > \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$. If $N$ is any integer greater than $\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$, the implication will hold for all $n>N$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it as a game between us:

I choose a small number $\epsilon$ then you have to see if you can find an $N$ such that for all $n > N$ the terms of the sequence are within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

If you can always do so, then the sequence converges - you win.

Comment: I think this video explained it well http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzw9ll80Zbc beginning at 3:08. What if he chose M = 1, n = 2 wouldn't be in the range of $\epsilon$ and $L$.

Comment: Sorry - I get the message "this video is currently unavailable".

Comment: I think I understand what the definition is trying to say. If I were to choose $N$ to be 5, I would have to choose an $n>5$, say $a_6$. If $a_6$ is within $\epsilon$ of $L$ then the sequence will converge.

Comment: Not exactly. It is not enough for just $a_6$ to be within $\epsilon$ of $L$, but rather ALL $a_n$ for $n>5$ have to be within $\epsilon$ of $L$.

Comment: I edited my question to contain an example in the book which I did not understand. Why does $N$ have to be greater than $\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$ for $n>N$ to be true? If $N$ is less than $\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$ wouldn't the implication of $n>N$ still be true?

Comment: If you take $N$ less than $1/\epsilon$, then that would not guarantee that $1/n$ has to be less than $\epsilon$ for ALL $n>N$. For example, if I take $\epsilon$ to be $1/10$, then to ensure that $1/n < 1/10$, you have to have $n$ bigger than 10.

Comment: I seem to be having a hard time understanding this. For your example choosing $\epsilon$ to be $1/10$, I know that $n$ has to be greater than $10$ but what role does $N$ play?

Answer (score 1):

Is this over the real numbers? Let us look at a simple case. Suppose $L=0$. Give me an $\epsilon>0$. What the definition tells me is that I can find a positive integer $N$ such that after the Nth term , that is $n>N$ , $-\epsilon<a_n<\epsilon$. Pictorially, this means that the terms of the sequence eventually get trapped in between the lines $y=\epsilon$ and $y=-\epsilon$. More generally your lines are $y=\epsilon+L$ and $y=L-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive definition to me is as follows:

Your sequence $a_n$ converges if:

"No matter how close to $L$ I want your sequence $a_n$ to be you can find a large index $N$ so that after that point the rest of your sequence is that close $L$"

No matter how close is characterized by the fact that $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small.