# Verify the limit using the definition of convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know that the definition is:

"A sequence $(s_n)$ is said to converge to the real number $s$ provided that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $N \leq n$ implies that $|s_n - s | < \epsilon$".

So here is an exercise in the problem section of the chapter:

"Verify the limit using the definition of convergence of a sequence that:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[]{n}}{n+2} = 0$"

I don't know how to really start. I guess, given any $\epsilon$ we want to make $|\frac{\sqrt[]{n}}{n+2} - 0| < \epsilon$. Looking at:[The definition of a sequence converging.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584012/the-definition-of-a-sequence-converging)

So, lets pick a value for epsilon, $\epsilon = 0.5$. Now we have to find a natural number $N$ s.t. for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|s_n - s| < \epsilon$. So, we have to solve for $n$ in $\frac{\sqrt[]{n}}{n+2} < \frac{1}{2}$.

Couldn't that be quite messy with other limit problems? I suppose we could use the fact if $a < b$ and $b < c$, then $a < c$, but i'm not sure how exactly to find something larger than $\frac{\sqrt[]{n}}{n+2}$ .

Comment: It's $n \rightarrow \infty$, not $x \rightarrow \infty$. (Inside the limit).

Comment: whoops, sorry. Edited accordingly

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2}<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Now compare 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sim \varepsilon.$$

Comment: My trouble is finding the other $f(n)$ that is larger than my original $f(n)$.

Comment: Why do you want the 'the other $f(n)$' to be larger? You want $\sqrt{n}/n+2$ to be small and clearly we can make it small by taking $n>1/\varepsilon^2$.

Comment: What? We're trying to make another sequence $f_n$ s.t. it is greater than our original sequence but less than epsilon. My trouble is creating/finding that sequence

Comment: Yes this $f_n$ is $\sqrt{n}/n$...

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that $\left | \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2} \right | <\epsilon$ for a sufficiently large $n$. Since $\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2} > 0$:

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{n+2} <\epsilon$$

$$\sqrt{n}< \epsilon (n+2)$$

Since both members of the inequality are positive, we can square them and the inequalilty holds:

$$n < \epsilon^2 (n+2)^2$$

$$n - \epsilon^2 n^2 - 4\epsilon^2 n - 4\epsilon ^2 < 0$$

$$-\epsilon^2 n^2 + (1-4\epsilon^2)n - 4\epsilon^2 < 0$$

Which is true for a sufficiently large $n$.